# Trying to add new row to parse but nothing is being added-Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to add a new row to my parse core, but when I try to use the "put" method, no row is added to parse.

Thanks in advance

Here is a screenshot of my parse core:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
Parse.initialize(reviewActivity.this, "x", "y");
ParseObject dataObject = new ParseObject("HelpSTL");
dataObject.put("rating", String.valueOf(rating));
dataObject.put("objectID", 1);
dataObject.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code has some problems.

1. type of rating is number so u don't have to convert rating to string.
2. There is no row with the name "objectID" and u don't need to provide value for "objectId".
3. initialize parse in applicaiton class.

Comment: What do you mean by initialize parse in application class? Haven't I already done that?

Comment: I think you are initialising it in reviewActivity class.

Comment: Nevermind, the String.valueOf was screwing my code up; thanks!